# Quiet MSI Exec from Shell Execute

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute, windows-installer

I am having some trouble getting an MSI to install "quietly". I can get the MSI to run normally like so:

```
TCHAR argmnt[] = TEXT("open");
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
wchar_t run[256];
wcscpy_s(run, L"C:\\Users\\");
wcscat_s(run, username);
wcscat_s(run, L"\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\index.msi");
ShellExecute(NULL, argmnt, run, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

But if I add "/quiet" to the last line like so:

```
wcscat_s(run, L"\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\index.msi /quiet");
```

It will not install the MSI at all. I have tried adding a TCHAR variable with the arguments like this:

```
TCHAR params[] = TEXT("/quiet");
```

With the updated shellexecute like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, argmnt, run, params, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you try the quite switch in the 'argmnt'

Comment: @LuckyChingi Yes, that does not work either.

Comment: sorry! the 4th option is the parameter - HINSTANCE ShellExecute(
  _In_opt_ HWND    hwnd,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpOperation,
  _In_     LPCTSTR lpFile,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpParameters,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpDirectory,
  _In_     INT     nShowCmd
);

Comment: That is why I tried to put it there, still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msi file is not an executable file so try to pass to your run parameter "msiexec.exe" and to params parameter path to your msi file with /qn (complete silent) or /qb (with progress bar only):

```
wcscpy_s(run, "msiexec.exe");
wcscpy_s(params, L"C:\\Users\\");
wcscpy_s(params, username);
wcscpy_s(params, L"\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\index.msi /qn");
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to us [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa)(). Before you call it you prepare the [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shellexecuteinfoa) data structure. 
Then you can use the **lpParameters** member for the *"/quiet"* flag.